# discord.js - TypeError [COMMAND_INTERACTION_OPTION_TYPE]: Option "user" is of type: STRING; expected USER

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When I run the script for my discord bot and use /warn remove it keeps throwing an error that user is of type string expected USER. It says the error is happening between lines 69:42 and I can't find the issue.

```
module.exports = {
    category: 'Moderation',
    description: 'Warn a user',

    permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
    
    slash: true,
    guildOnly: true,

    options: [
        {
            type: 'SUB_COMMAND',
            name: 'remove',
            description: 'Removes a warning from the user',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'user',
                    type: 'USER',
                    description: 'The user to remove the warning from',
                    required: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'STRING',
                    description: 'The ID of the warning to remove',
                    required: true,
                },
            ],
        }
    ],

    callback: async ({ guild, member: staff, interaction }) => {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('user')

        if (subCommand === 'remove') {
            const warning = await warnSchema.findByIdAndDelete(id)

            return {
                custom: true,
                content: `Removed warning ${warning.id} from  <@${user?.id}>`,
                allowedMentions: {
                    users: []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't post all the code because it seemed like it would be too much searching but this is the code that is causing the error.

Comment: I think, the `type:` must be `json` or `text`

Comment: How do I fix it if that's the case?

Comment: In normal case of `javascript` the `type:` function on `ajax` we calling it as `POST` or `GET` might try of those as well. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same issue today and as far as i could check on the [official discord.js documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands), what you need to do is to specify the type of the user.
In our case, it is **type 6**.

(it gives us: `type: 6,`)

You need to edit your code like that:

```
            {
                name: 'user',
                type: 6,
                description: 'The user to remove the warning from',
                required: true,
            },
```

then when your code is gonna execute the following `const user = interaction.options.getUser('user')` function, it will work as intended since you specified the correct value.

I hope it helps you or anyone else!